# How to do a backtrack search with parser combinators?

Tags: parsing, haskell, trifecta

I have a list of parsers e.g. `[string "a",string "ab"]` that are "overlapping". I can change neither the parsers themselves nor their order.

With these parsers I want to parse a sequence of tokens that would each be exact matches for one of the parsers e.g. `"aaaab", "ab", "abab"` but not `"abb"`

Without parsers I would just implement a dept first search, but I would like to solve this with parsers.

I get about this far:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Text.Trifecta

parsers = [string "a",string "ab"]

parseString (many (choice parsers) <* eof) mempty "aab"
```

This fails because it will parse `"a"` both times, and not backtrack because `choice` doesn't do that. And further, `string "a"` has succeeded both times so the consumed input probably can't be retrieved anymore.
How can implement a parser that can backtrack and produce a list of parse results e.g. `Success ["a","ab"]`?

If I require the input to have the tokens separated, I still can't make it work:

This works:

```
parseString (try (string "a" <* eof) <|> (string "ab" <*eof)) mempty "ab"
```

But this does not:

```
parseString (try (foldl1 (<|>) $ map (\x -> x <* eof) parsers)) mempty "ab"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `try` level is performed too high. You should perform it on the individual parsers. For example:

```
parseString (foldl1 (<|>) $ map (\x -> try (x <* eof)) parsers) mempty "ab"
```

---

In the original parser you wrote:

```
parseString ((try (string "a" <* eof)) <|> (string "ab" <*eof)) mempty "ab"
```

Notice that the left operand of `<|>` is `try (string "a" <* eof)` with `try` included.

whereas in the one you performed with `foldl1`, you wrote:

```
parseString (try ((string "a" <* eof) <|> (string "ab" <*eof))) mempty "ab"
```

So here is the `try` not part of the left operand. As a result, if the first parser fails, the "cursor" will not return to the point where it made the decision to try the first operand.

---

We can improve the above, by making use of [**`asum :: (Foldable t, Alternative f) -> t (f a) -> f a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:asum):

```
import Data.Foldable(asum)

parseString (asum (map (\x -> try (x <* eof)) parsers)) mempty "ab"
```

Comment: A left fold seems inappropriate here. Why not use a right fold?

Comment: Also, a partial fold is sad. `foldr (<|>) empty` should do the trick, no?

Comment: @dfeuer: yes, I only demonstrated the "minimal change" here. But indeed, this can be improved.